# Trading View plotting false statements?

Tags: boolean, pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm having an issue with pinescript plotting false statements as part of the plot function. For example, I can type a basic true false formula such as (close < 30) and set my plot to put a lime background against all candles in which the statement is true. But trading view has been acting up and not distinguishing true and false in some situations. Why is this happening? Can anyone help?

```
if close < 30
    longstay := false
    shortstay := true
    
debugger = shortstay ? color.new(color.lime, 30) : na
bgcolor(debugger)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("test",overlay=true)
var longstay=true
var shortstay=false
if close < 30
    longstay := false
    shortstay := true
else
    longstay := true
    shortstay := false
debugger = shortstay ? color.new(color.lime, 30) : na
bgcolor(debugger)
```

You have been setting the value of variable shortstay as true when close was below 30
But it remained true for all the further candles
So I have changed its value to false when the close is above 30 and now it will only show colored bars when the condition is true

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Code only answers does not provide any value to the community. Please take some time to read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) FAQ page.